# `Class<Component>` meaning in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Sorry for the awful title (I couldn't come up with a better one).

I'm taking a look at `Vue` code, and I've found this:

```
export function initMixin (Vue: Class<Component>) { // ... }
```

What does `Class<Component>` means in this context? And the colon? In this case, we are passing the variable `Vue` to the `initMixin` function. Vue it's just a factory class declaration. I've been soaking myself in ES2015 and I still don't understand what it does.

The file is https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/next/src/core/instance/init.js, line 12.

Thanks!

Comment: it is using [flow](https://flowtype.org) which is a typed extension to javascript

Comment: Looks like it. Thanks, man! If you move this as an answer, I cap upvote and approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is using [flow](https://flowtype.org), which is a typed extension to Javascript.

You can find out the exact Javascript variant by reading the [.babelrc](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/next/.babelrc) file. You can see it is using two presets: `es2015` and [`flow-vue`](https://github.com/yyx990803/babel-preset-flow-vue/blob/master/index.js)

In this case, `Vue: Class<Component>` declares a parameter `Vue` that have type of `Class<Component>`.

Comment: And specifically where `Vue: Component` wound indicate a `Vue` variable who's value is an _instance_ of `Component`, `Vue: Class<Component>` means `Vue` is constructor for an instance of `Component`.